# Differential (in)dependancies between cluster variables

Tags: reference-request, cluster-algebras

Let $ \mathcal A$ be the complex cluster algebra
obtained from the initial seed $(a,x, B)$  where : 
$x$ stands for a $n$-tuple $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of complex indeterminates, idem for $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n) $  and $B=(b_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ is the associated exchange matrix).

**Definition:** The *"$X$-mutation in the direction $k$"* is the birational map 
  $$x\mapsto \mu_k(x)=x'=(x'_i)_{i=1}^n$$ 
where
$$ x_k'=\frac{1}{x_k}  \; \quad \mbox{ and } \quad 
x_i'=x_i\left( 1+x_k^{-[b_{ik}]_+} 
\right)^{-b_{ik}}   \qquad \mbox{ for any }\quad i\neq k
$$
(with $[s]_+=\max(0,s)$ for any $s\in \mathbb R$).

**Definition:** The *"$A$-mutation in the direction $k$"* is the birational map 
 $$a\mapsto \mu_k(a)=a'=(a'_i)_{i=1}^n$$ where
$$ a_i'=a_i  \; \mbox{ if }\, i\neq k \quad \mbox{ and } \quad 
a_k'=\frac{1}{a_k}\left( 
\prod_{j \vert b_{kj} > 0} a_j^{b_{kj}} + \prod_{j \vert b_{kj} < 0} a_j^{-b_{kj}}
\right)  \, .
$$

(*Cf.* $\S$1.2.4 in V. Fock - A. Goncharov. *Cluster ensembles, quantization and the dilogarithm*. Ann. ÉNS (2009).)

By definition, the associated **$X$-cluster variables** (resp. **$A$-cluster variables**) (in Fock-Goncharov's terminology)  are all the rational functions $x'=x'(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ (resp. $a'=a'(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$) which can be obtained from the initial  $x_i$'s (resp. from the $a_i$'s) by  finite sequences of $X$-mutations (resp. of $A$-mutations) (note that the exchange matrix B mutates at each step  as well but it is pointless to give explicit formula for  the matrix mutations $B\mapsto \mu_k(B)$ here).

The following question mainly concerns the $X$-cluster variables :

**Question:** is it known whether  the following statement holds true or not :

given two X-cluster variables $x$ and $x'$,  one has : 
 $$ (\mathcal S)\qquad \quad dx \wedge dx' \equiv 0 \qquad \mbox{ if and only if }\qquad  x'=x \; \mbox{ or  } \; x'=1/x\; \mbox{ ?} $$

(Note : here "$dx$" stands for the total derivative of $x$ and " $\wedge$  " for the usual wedge product of differential algebra; moreover  " $x'=x$ or $x'=1/x$ "  has to be understood as an equality between two complex rational functions in the $x_i$'s).

1). If it is true and well known, a reference would be welcome;

2). If ($\mathcal S$) does not hold true in full generality, what about the case of cluster algebras of finite type (with or without frozen variables)?

3). More generally, if  ($\mathcal S$) does not hold true in full generality, are there some "natural  and nice" conditions  on $\mathcal A$ (i.e. on $B$) ensuring  that ($\mathcal S$) is satisfied?

4). (Not of primary interest): same questions but  for the $A$-cluster variables.

**Remark:**  looking at many explicit cases, I'm pretty sure that $(\mathcal S)$ indeed holds true in case 2) (more precisely : for finite type without frozen variables). This  must be well-known by peoples familiar with the theory of cluster algebras... but I'm not such a person!

Any help would be welcome. 
Thanks in advances!